# Customize Reorder ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: django

I have a problem customizing the manytomanyfield, is it possible to reorder the selected values/data? Example:

```
class Author(models.Model):
author_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

Let's say the Author model have the values of Jk Rowling, Jackie Chan, Bruce Lee, Chuck Norris. The ordering will be based on ID right? Can I customize it like what I want if which of them will be first selected? Also when I customize it, it will not affect the other Books. Like I have HP book and my author ordering will be Bruce Lee, Chuck Norris, Jk Rowling and Jackie Chan. Then, Django book will have the author ordering, Jackie Chan, Bruce Lee, Chuck Norris and Jk Rowling.

Every Book will have its own ordering. It will not be global. Once you changed the ordering from 1st book, the 2nd book will not be affected by the changed orering. I hope there's someone can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Meta [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering). For example

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
         ordering = ['author_name']
```

Or querysets [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) for specific query:

```
Author.objects.all().oreder_by('author_name')
```

To do what equinoxel suggested below, you'd add a field for ordering, and a method that respects it:

```
 class Book(models.Model):
     # ...
     authors_order = models.CharField(max_length=255)

     def get_ordered_authors(self):
         authors = self.authors.all()
         authors_by_id = [dict(author.id, author) for author in authors]
         for author_id in map(int, self.authors_order.split(",")):
             yield authors_by_id[author_id]
```

You'll also need to implement logic that keeps `book.authors` and `book.authors_order` in sync whenever the ordering is changed/set.

Comment: Uhm, This is not the one I'm looking for Alex. What I want is I will be the one who will customize the ordering, and this will not affect the entire model.

Comment: You'll need an intermediary model then. [Docs on doing this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: I think you can get away by just adding a "order" field in the Book model and then implementing some logic to deal with it. This would work if you have an "automatic" means (e.g. author/first_name/alpha). if you want manual ordering, then @AdamKG is correct.

Comment: Yup, I've added an example to this answer. The downside being that it limits the number of authors - more than a few dozen will risk hitting the field length limit - and you have to make sure to keep `book.authors` in sync. Although you could also forego having a `Book.authors` field at all, if you never need to query which books an author was involved in.

Comment: The authors_order field, what will I type there?